# Rotation of a Plane in 3d about a line

Tags: matrices, geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, rotations

I have a set of points in the XY planes, I want to translate them all to the YZ plane by rotating about a line. Basically,

[Here, in this cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHDot.png)

Imagine I have a list of points on 2376 plane, I want to translate those points in such a way that the points on plane 2367 land on the same location on the plane 2341. Is there a possible rotation matrix for this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your post accordingly

Comment: A few things to be aware of: (1) Every rotation in 3D space is a rotation around a line, but there are a lot of different lines to choose from. (2) There are eight different rotations that take the square $2367$ to the square $2341.$ (3) If you just want to move the square $2367$ and everything in its plane into the plane where $2341$ was, there are a lot more choices. (4) Rotation matrices only work for rotations around lines that pass through the point $(0,0,0).$ A rotation around the $y$ axis is one such rotation.

Comment: It's a little hard to relate the rotation described in terms of the cube's faces to the rotation described in terms of coordinate planes, because there are no coordinate axes marked in the picture. To reconcile the two descriptions we would have to make the axes cross at point $2,$ so point $2$ has coordinates $(0,0,0),$ while point $6$ has coordinates $(1,0,0)$ ($x$ axis points down), point $3$ has coordinates $(0,1,0)$ ($y$ axis points right), and point $1$ has coordinates $(0,0,1).$ That's an unusual point of view to use when looking at $x,y,z$ axes, so it may confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  I'm not going to tell you the answer, because I want to show you how to find the answer yourself.  Teach a person to fish, and they will be happy fishing for the rest of their life, and so on :).

First, consider counterclockwise rotation on a 2D plane:
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{matrix} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{1}\label{AC1}$$
Essentially, $\eqref{AC1}$ is just
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned} x_1 &= -y_0 \\ y_1 &= x_0 \end{aligned}\right.$$
Feel free to try some coordinate pairs to see how this works.  As an example, $(1,0) \to (0,1) \to (-1,0) \to (0,-1) \to (1,0)$.  Drawing the points on a paper, or say [at Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), can be very useful here.

Second, consider the identity transformation in 3D:
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{2}\label{AC2}$$
Essentially, the rows corresponding to the coordinate axis that stays put, are all zeros except $1$ on the diagonal.  If you play with this for a second, you'll realize why that is.

We can combine the two, by ignoring the row and column that corresponds to the coordinate axis that stays unchanged.  This gives us three rotation matrices:
$\mathbf{R}_{xy}$ rotates the $xy$ plane by ninety degrees, leaving $z$ coordinates intact:
$$\mathbf{R}_{xy} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{XY}\label{ACXY}$$
$\mathbf{R}_{xz}$ rotates the $xz$ plane by ninety degrees, leaving $y$ coordinates intact:
$$\mathbf{R}_{xz} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{XZ}\label{ACXZ}$$
$\mathbf{R}_{yz}$ rotates the $yz$ plane by ninety degrees, leaving $x$ coordinates intact:
$$\mathbf{R}_{yz} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \tag{YZ}\label{ACYZ}$$
(Yes, one of those *is* the matrix OP is looking for, I believe.)

Pure rotation and mirroring matrices that do not scale or skew are *orthonormal*.  Their inverse is their transpose,
$$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T}$$
which means that if you want to rotate in the other direction, just transpose the matrix.  (Rotation in the opposite direction is obviously the inverse rotation, right?)